# Satoshi's IP address(es)?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto

Does anyone know Satoshi Nakamoto's IP address(es)? The forums he posted on should be able to figure that out. He posted on [p2pfoundation.org](http://p2pfoundation.ning.com/profile/SatoshiNakamoto), [bitcointalk.org](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=3), and the [cryptography mail archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=cryptography%40metzdowd.com&q=satoshi%20nakamoto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote from: theymos [BitcoinTalk.org admin] on April 17, 2013, 11:20:31 PM](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=178330.msg1869406#msg1869406):

> I'll probably release Satoshi's PMs and logged IPs addresses in ~8 years. This'd probably be of great historical interest. (Though he always used Tor, as far as I can tell.)